# Assign Google Analytics Permission To Whole Company Domain

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'd like to know if there is a way to assign Google Analytics Website permissions to a whole group of users (***@abc.com) instead of individual users ?

Regards,
Alok

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to build a dashboard the whole company can see, maybe you should try [Server Side Auth](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/) allows you to programmatically add users to an account.

I don't believe there's a way to add evernbody in one shot through the UI.